# Specify Initialization for each Spark executor before compute on RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, classloader

I want to make sure this class/static-block to be initialized in every JVM as early as possible because it suppose to be(in order to work properly),

```
// java
class SecurityInitializer {
    static {
        Security.addProvider(myprovider);
    }
}

// Equivalent in Scala, use companion object to get something similar to static block in Java
object SecurityInitializer {
    Security.addProvider(myprovider)
}
```

I know it`s easy to do this in driver , but how do I force this code to run in **executor** ideally before creation of sparkcontext?

Looking for answers in Scala but any suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

OK it`s an official usecase now, starting from 2.4, the name is ExecutorPlugin
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24918